# Make jquery toggle work with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following code on my website: http://jsfiddle.net/dJLK3/1/
As you can see, it works just fine.

The problem is: those divs and link triggers come from a database. Today I have 1, tomorrow it can be 10...

I can not figure out how to convert it and make it work without needing to right lot's of codes like link1, link2, link3, link4, link5 and so on...

Anyone? :)

Comment: could you expand or show some code on how you are actually getting the divs from the database (and in what format)?

Answer (score 2):

Use `data` attr and `jQuery.data`. [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

**Update**:
according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681704/make-jquery-toggle-work-with-dynamic-content/11681869#comment15487519_11681869) comment.

**html**

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="link" data-slide-content="div1">Link1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link" data-slide-content="div2">Link2</a>
</div>
<div id="div1" class="slide"></div>
<div id="div2" class="slide"></div>​
```

**js**

```
$('.menu').on('click', '.link', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('slideContent');
    $('.slide').not('#' + id).slideUp(function() {
        $('#' + id).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**​css**

```
.slide {
    display: none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dJLK3/15/)

References:

- **slideUp** - http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/
- **slideToggle** - http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Almost...can you make it slideUp the div before toggling the next one? this way it closes yellow and opens in red or close the red and then opens in yellow...got it? :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Here's a fiddle with a possible answer - [FIDDLE - Update - With new requirements](http://jsfiddle.net/dJLK3/14/)

Code posted here for clarification

```
<div id='link_collection'>
    <a href="#" class="link">Link1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Link2</a>
</div>
<div id='div_collection'>
    <div class='div current'></div>
    <div class='div'></div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link_collection').on('click', '.link', function() {
        var divCollection = $('#div_collection .div'),
            index = $(this).index(), hasClickedMeAgain,
            current = divCollection.filter('.current');

        hasClickedMeAgain = current.index() === index;
        if (hasClickedMeAgain){
            current.slideToggle();
            return false;
        }
        current.slideUp(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('current');
            divCollection.eq(index).addClass('current').slideToggle();
        });
    })
});
```

This way, you don't need to keep tag of anything. Just keep inserting the div and link in the order in which they arrive, and the code then handles itself. All the best.

Comment: it's not working...take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/dJLK3/10/ it never closes and it's toggling between both divs

Comment: Try changing the colors, I've added a few console statements for your benefit, it'll wokr

Comment: It's working just fine but my code will have more than 1 link_collection and div_collection...I mean, I will repeat your html code based on how many data I have on my database. Anyway, thanks for all your effort to help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you? Use the same class attribute for all of them. And have the following code on document.ready() to assign on click events:

HTML:

```
<a class="ui-link-option">Link 1</a>
<a class="ui-link-option">Link 2</a>

<div class="ui-link-option-text">Text Here 1</div>
<div class="ui-link-option-text">Text Here 2</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("a.ui-link-option").each(
  function (index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data("index", index);
    $this.bind("click", function(e) {
      var $this = $(this);
      var linkIndex = $this.data("index");
      $("div.ui-link-option-text").each(
        function (index) {
          if (index == linkIndex) {
            $(this).slideToggle();
          } else {
            $(this).hide();
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I can not set the same class because it's always 2 divs with 2 triggers..take a look: http://bit.ly/MaEV2g try to click on PROGRAMACAO and on TEXTO CURATORIAL

Comment: you can still use the same class name for all anchor tags and the same class name for all div tags. check updated code. (assuming there is a corresponding div tag for each a tag.)